# Get the value of a dice in a 5dice game from another window

Tags: wpf, random, user-controls, dice

I'm developing a 5 dice game in WPF. I have a usercontrol where I made the design of a dice. Then on my mainWindow I added this usercontrol 5 times (so this are my dices).

I have a class named ScoreCheck. In that class I write the code to get the value of the dice (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6).

The problem is that I can do something like this in my usercontrol dice:

```
int throw = rand.Next(1, 7);
switch (throw)
            {
                case 1:
                    dso1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(dicecolor);
                    dso2.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(dicecolor);
                    dso3.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(dicecolor);
                    dso4.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(eyecolor);
                    dso5.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(dicecolor);
                    dso6.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(dicecolor);
                    dso7.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(dicecolor);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    dso1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(dicecolor);
                    dso2.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(dicecolor);
                    dso3.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(eyecolor);
                    dso4.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(dicecolor);
                    dso5.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(eyecolor);
                    dso6.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(dicecolor);
                    dso7.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(dicecolor);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    dso1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(dicecolor);
                    dso2.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(dicecolor);
                    dso3.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(eyecolor);
                    dso4.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(eyecolor);
                    dso5.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(eyecolor);
                    dso6.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(dicecolor);
                    dso7.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(dicecolor);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    dso1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(eyecolor);
                    dso2.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(dicecolor);
                    dso3.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(eyecolor);
                    dso4.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(dicecolor);
                    dso5.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(eyecolor);
                    dso6.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(dicecolor);
                    dso7.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(eyecolor);
                    break;

                case 5:
                    dso1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(eyecolor);
                    dso2.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(dicecolor);
                    dso3.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(eyecolor);
                    dso4.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(eyecolor);
                    dso5.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(eyecolor);
                    dso6.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(dicecolor);
                    dso7.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(eyecolor);
                    break;

                case 6:
                    dso1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(eyecolor);
                    dso2.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(eyecolor);
                    dso3.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(eyecolor);
                    dso4.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(dicecolor);
                    dso5.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(eyecolor);
                    dso6.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(eyecolor);
                    dso7.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(eyecolor);
                    break;
            }

Console.WriteLine(throw);
```

So now I get the value of all dices. Something like this: 2 6 4 1 5 1.

But I don't want this. I want them dice by dice on another window so I can check the score. So on my mainWindow I named my dices: dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4 and dice5. So I want to do something like this in my ScoreCheck.

```
var getmainwindow= Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().SingleOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(getmainwindow.dice1.throw);
```

But then my output is always 0.

So does anyone know how to get the value of my dice from another window?

Answer (score 0):

Try this line of code:

`var mwaanspreken = ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow);`

`Console.WriteLine(mwaanspreken.steen1.worp);`

Alternatively you can try using application setting.

in Visual Studio go to "Project>WpfApp1 Properties..."

Add a property there and name it "worpsetting", make sure it is of an int type and set to user scope.

Try this code to access the setting:

`Properties.Settings.Default.worpsetting = ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).steen1.worp;`

If you want to read it to a Textbox or something like that you will have to call the "ToString" method:

`Textbox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.worpsetting.ToString();`

Comment: Nope still null @Dark Templar

Comment: Hmm what about using application settings?

Comment: How do you mean application settings? @Dark Templar